# redis sentinel notification script not working in windows

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

Redis sentinel notification script not working in windows.

The script is written using power shell and is called from bat file which i am providing to the redis sentinel config notification section.

Trying two different sentinel configuration as mentioned below

1.
sentinel notification-script mymaster "D:\Redis-64.2.8.17\notificationScript\qwe.bat"

With this configuration redis-server running as sentinel is getting crashed as i am able to see event log but i am not getting any log in the redis stdout.log.

2.
sentinel client-reconfig-script mymaster "D:\Redis-64.2.8.17\notificationScript\qwe.bat".

With this configuration , redis-server running as sentinel is getting started but the event is not firing.

Comment: why did you use stackexchange.redis tag? is that what you use as a client?

Comment: yes.i use stackexchange.redis as my client.

Comment: I guess you better get in touch with https://github.com/msopentech/redis/issues